# Is there any way keep part of my code in a seperate document?

Tags: javascript, html

This might be a dumb question, but I'm working a theme for my Tumblr blog and the block where all the data regarding rendering posts is fairly large and just tends to be a pain in the ass to have in the middle of everything. I was wondering if there was any way that I could have this block in a different file and insert it in to my code with just a line or two instead of having this 150 line piece of code in the middle of my document that I'm never going to touch.

I have a feeling that the best way to do this would be with JS but I'd prefer pure HTML if possible.

Comment: What you could do is use PHP, and use `include 'code.php';`.

Comment: you could try the `<iframe>` element - it's not exactly what you're looking for but it might work. If it was me I would use AngularJS and put different bits of HTML in custom directives, and just have the directives in the main index.html file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing the block of data you want to move to a separate file is also HTML code? If so, you can do this: Move that block of code into a separate .html file and insert this line into your page:

```
<object type="text/html" data="yourFile.html" style="height:300px; width:96%; margin:2%;"></object>
```

The height, width, and margin should be like you actually want it. The values in there at the moment is just an example. The important part is the "data" attribute.

If you don't want the external HTML code to display, you can set the visibility of the object to hide it.

Hope this is what you were looking for.